# ACF pro repeater field random row output

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

i have this code

```
  <?php

  $rows = get_field('brand_section', 56 ); // get all the rows
  $rand_row = $rows[ array_rand( $rows ) ]; // get a random row
  $rand_row_image = $rand_row['brand_specific' ]; // get the sub field value

  // Note
  // $first_row_image = 123 (image ID)

  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $rand_row_image, 'full' );
  // url = $image[0];
  // width = $image[1];
  // height = $image[2];
  ?>

  <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

And what im trying to do with this is to ouutput one group from my reapeater field.

my acf field structure is like this:

```
  -reapeater field
  --group(that can be reapeted)
  ---img
  ---link
  ---link2
```

and the error is that its not outputting anything like the img src is unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question, but I do know that [repeater fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) need to be `get_sub_field()` or `the_sub_field` (depending on your template usage), instead of `get_field()`.

Maybe that is the source of your problem.